# failed to upgrade git on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04

my git version is
git version 1.9.1
I want to upgrade it to >=2.0.
I did the following steps:

```
➜  ~ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
➜  ~ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*                                                        
➜  ~ sudo apt-get clean                                                                      
➜  ~ sudo apt-get update
```

then I get the errors:

> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   Hash Sum mismatch
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-i386/Packages
>   Hash Sum mismatch
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   Hash Sum mismatch
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages
>   Hash Sum mismatch
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

Comment: This really belongs on the askubuntu.com website. It doesn't really have to do with coding, but a lot to do with the Ubuntu package manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be an issue with the mirror you're updating from, so I'd find a different mirror (steps outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)).

Comment: it doesn't help me much.
I add the lines into my source.list.
I am also using the nearest source from my location.